# Conditional Subtraction within the same column using SAS

Tags: sql, sas, conditional-statements, subtraction, proc

here is a portion of a data set I have named “antibody” :

```
Row          Subject        Type               Procedure           Measurement              Output
1               500         Intial              Invasive             20                        20
2               500          Initial            Surface              35                        35
3               500          Followup          Invasive             54                        54-20
4               428          Followup          Outer                 29                        29-10
5               765          Seventh           Other                 13                       13-19
6                500          Followup          Surface              98                       98-35
7                428          Initial             Outer            10                        10                
8                765          Initial              Other            19                        19     
9                610          Third              Invasive            66                       66-17
10               610          Initial             Invasive            17                       17
```

I was trying to use proc sql to perform this. The goal is to subtract the numbers in the "MEASUREMENT" column based on the "SUBJECT", "TYPE" and “PROCEDURE” columns. If two values in the “SUBJECT” column match and  two values in the “PROCEDURE” column match, then the initial measurement should be subtracted from the other measurement. For example, the initial measurement in row 1 (20) should be subtracted from the followup measurement in row 3 (54) because the subject (500) and procedure (Invasive) match. Furthermore, the initial measurement in row 8 (19) should be subtracted from the seventh measurement in row 5 (13) because the subject (765) and procedure (Other) match. The result should form the "OUTPUT" column.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a hash object approach

```
data have;
input Subject Type $ 5-12 Procedure $ 15-22 Measurement;
datalines;
500 Initial   Invasive  20 
500 Initial   Surface   35 
500 Followup  Invasive  54 
428 Followup  Outer     29 
765 Seventh   Other     13 
500 Followup  Surface   98 
428 Initial   Outer     10 
765 Initial   Other     19 
610 Third     Invasive  66 
610 Initial   Invasive  17 
;

data want (drop=rc _Measurement);
   if _N_ = 1 then do;
      declare hash h (dataset : "have (rename=(Measurement=_Measurement) where=(Type='Initial'))");
      h.definekey ('Subject');
      h.definedata ('_Measurement');
      h.definedone();
   end;

   set have;
   _Measurement=.;

   if Type ne 'Initial' then rc = h.find();
   Measurement = sum (Measurement, -_Measurement);
run;
```

EDIT:

```
data want (drop=rc _Measurement);
   if _N_ = 1 then do;
      declare hash h (dataset : "have (rename=(Measurement=_Measurement) where=(Type='Initial'))");
      h.definekey ('Subject');
      h.definedata ('_Measurement');
      h.definedone();
   end;

   set have;
   _Measurement=.;

   if Type ne 'Initial' then rc = h.find();
   NewMeasurement = ifn(Measurement=., ., sum (Measurement, -_Measurement));
run;
```

Comment: How can I account for missing values in the "measurement" column? In addition, I noticed that this program updates the "measurement" column. How can I have the updates be created in a new column while keeping the "measurement" column? Would you mind editing the program to incorporate this? Thank you in advance and thank you for the insightful response!

Comment: What do you mean by 'account for missing values'? Your second request is not a problem, I will update my answer..

Comment: For example, if there are rows with blank cells in the "measurement" column", I wanted to know if the created "output" column could be created while have the corresponding cells remain blank in the "output" column.

Comment: See my updated answer. I think this is what you want.

Comment: Good, glad you found your answer. Please remember to close the thread both here and at the SAS Community.

Comment: Hi, I noticed that  record _n_=6 (Subject 500, Procedure Surface) has NewMeasurement = 78?
The initial "Surface" record has Measurement = 35, and _n_ = 6 has Measurement = 98.
Shouldn't NewMeasurement be 63?